# Accommodating empy function parameter without default value

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a simple function in python 3.6 to find the distance between two points in n-dimensional space.  I pass the coordinates as one-dimensional lists to my function.  Here is what I have written:

```
def Distance(a: list[float], b: list[float]):
    dimension = len(a)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(dimension):
        sum += (b[i]-a[i])**2
    return math.sqrt(sum)
```

This should work just fine if both `a` and `b` are passed explicitly.  But I want to add additional functionality: if only `a` is passed, its distance from the origin will be calculated.

In C++, the language I am most familiar with, I would do this using function overloading.  In that case, the two functions would simply have a different number of parameters.  But this isn't an option for me in Python.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Edit:
The updated definition

```
 def Distance(a: List[float], b=None):
    if b:
        arg = sum((x1 - x2)**2 for x1, x2 in zip(a,b))
    else:
        arg = sum(x**2 for x in a)
    return math.sqrt(arg)
```

works for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idiomatic definition could be

```
def distance(a, b=None):
    from math import sqrt
    d2=sum((x1-x2)**2 for x1,x2 in zip(a,b)) if b else sum(x**2 for x in a))
    return sqrt(d2)
```

I confide that it's possible to use type hints as well, but I'm not an expert.

As a final remark, you used `sum` as a name, while it's recommended that you do not mask builtin names (I have used  the `sum` builtin in my function definition)

Answer (score 1):

The prototype must indeed be with `None`, so you have to change the function types because `None` is obviously not a list:

```
def Distance(a: list[float], b=None):
```

Then:

```
if not b:
    b = [0.] * dimension
```

Comment: This would work for distance from the origin, but what about the first case where I actually do want to pass two non-zero coordinates?  Wouldn't the interpreter object to passing a list as the second parameter to a function with this definition?

Comment: No, why would it be a problem? We are not constraining it to any type.